# Java8's Base64.Encoder has a private constructor

Tags: base64, java-8

That constructor enables url-safe, no padded encoding. Access to the predefined encoders is through static methods on Base64. Unfortunately though, the urlSafeEncoder() allows padding. There's no was to get to an Encoder that is url-safe and has no padding.

Anyone know a way round this, other than just removing the trailing equals signs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [withoutPadding()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#withoutPadding--)?

> Returns an encoder instance that encodes equivalently to this one, but without adding any padding character at the end of the encoded byte data.

Comment: You bueaty! I'm not sure how I missed that.